# Wrong IP address in comment section

Tags: comments

I have noticed that the last few times in which I have linked to an old post of mine from my latest post, my IP address in the Comments section is wrong (sometimes my IP address appears in the form 192.x.x.x).

Since I am not proxied or anything, why does this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that by comment you actually mean a trackback/pingback. Those are sent from your server and not your computer and since in this case it sent from your server to itself it probably uses the local IP for the communication. 192.X.X.X is an IP range reserved for local in LAN communication same as the 10.X.X.X range.

Comment: Yes, I am talking about pingbacks, which appear under the Comments section. What you say does make sense, but why is it then that when a local IP is NOT used, I get different public IPs? And I mean totally different, as if they came from different regions in the world.

Comment: because it is from other servers  and computers? Hard to give any more intelligent answer without actually looking at your data.

Comment: Yeah, apparently in pingbacks the possible IP is more random. When I comment I usually come out with the right IP...

Comment: What other data would you need to give a better answer?

Comment: Access to your comments section, but I don't think it will change the answer. pingback from your own site will have local IPs, pingbacks from other servers will have their IP, true comments will have the IP of the PC from which they where sent.

Comment: The question still is why pingbacks from my own site have different IPs, but marked as accepted anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This Might help:

If you are using a normal hosting,add following lines to wp-config.php:

```
 if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
   $behindproxy = explode(',',$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']);
   $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = $behindproxy[0];
 }
```

**Ref: http://ispire.me/wordpress-wrong-comment-ip/, https://www.benjaminwiedmann.net/wordpress-behind-reverse-proxy-fix-wrong-ip-insert-x-forwarded-for-ip.html
 I havn't checked the solution personally.**